# Qt, Linux, С++. Кто может мешать связи по TCP/IP [решено]?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, tcp-ip

Написал небольшую библиотечку для синхронизации данных между программами. Есть очередь сообщений. Есть сервер, цепляющийся к очереди, открывающий порт и отвечающий на запросы типа "дай все сообщения", "дай сообщения с такого-то времени", "дай сообщения за последние n мс" и так далее. Есть клиент, цепляющийся к аналогичной очереди, и периодически опрашивающий сервера с указанными адресами/портами, занося новые сообщения в очередь. Подключается, опрашивает и отключается. Написал несколько программ, обменивающихся через такие очереди. Под `Windows` всё работает в любых версиях от `W7` до `W10`, проверял c версиями `Qt` `4.7.1`, `4.8.6`, `5.5.1`. Под `Linux` (`Ubuntu 14.04`, `Qt 5.5.1`) тоже работает практически всё. Проблема в слове "практически".

Итак, есть программы **A**, **B**, **C**. **B** опрашивает несколько источников (**A**) и формирует выходную очередь, которую опрашивают несколько клиентов (**С**). Доставка от **A** к **B** или от **A** к **C** работает всегда. А вот от **B** к **C** иногда, если **С** запущена позже, чем **B**, связь не налаживается - идут timeout'ы и порча пакетов. При этом, если **B** и **C** находятся на одном узле, всё работает. Пробовал для отладки поднимать на ноутбуке виртуальные машины `Virtualbox` и запускать **B** и **C** в разных виртуалках или одну в виртуалке, другую на хосте - всё работает, даже если сетевые задержки сильно увеличивать. Проблемы появляются только при работе между разными физическими компами. Попробовал пересобирать **B** под `Qt 4.8.6` - проблема появляется реже, но всё равно иногда остаётся. Если запускать **B** в виндовой версии, через `Wine` - всё тоже работает. Сетевые экраны отключены. Порты (9200-9300), используемые для сервера, никем не заняты, после запуска программ-серверов (**A**, **B**) сканер показывает, что они (порты) открыты.

Сейчас собираю на работе тестовый стенд (несколько узлов с `Linux`) для того, чтобы запустить **B** под отладчиком. Но в целом ситуация вызывает у меня глубочайшее недоумение, так как:

1. один и тот же код работает между A и B, между A и C, но не между B и C
2. один и тот же код работает между разными виртуальными машинами, но не между разными физическими
3. ... в сборке для `Windows`, но не в сборке для `Linux`.
4. ... если C запущена раньше, чем B, но не наоборот.

Код проверен `Valgrind`'ом и `cppcheck`'ом. Натыкался ли кто-нибудь на похожие "грабли", можете ли предположить хоть одну причину такого странного поведения?

**Update:** Всё страньше и страньше. Собрал тестовый стенд - и не могу воспроизвести проблему. Те же самые **A**, **B** и **C** цепляются друг к другу во всех возможных комбинациях. Чувствую, придётся запасной switch на объект везти.

**Update2:** Удалось воспроизвести проблему на стенде. Цепляю к одному **B** несколько **C**, через некоторое время часть клиентов (**C**) перестаёт цепляться. Что удивительно: когда клиент цепляться перестал, я пробую с его машины пинговать машину, на которой развёрнут сервер (**B**) - и она не пингуется. И начинает пинговаться только после того, как машина **B** в свою очередь начнёт пинговать клиентскую (**С**). У меня появилось подозрение, что Ubuntu воспринимает эту кучу запросов, приходящую с клиента, как DOS-атаку, и блокирует хост клиента. Осталось найти, где в настройках системы это прописано, и отключить.

**Update3:** Ситуация действительно очень похожа на защиту от DDOS-атаки. И такая версия объясняет, почему связь между **A** и **B** работает, а между **B** и **C** - нет. К одному источнику данных (**A**) цепляется максимум один промежуточный обработчик (**B**), а вот к нему может цепляться несколько клиентов **C**. И именно обращения на один порт с разных узлов, видимо, интерпретируются как DDOS-атака. При этом первый подключившийся клиент остаётся работоспособным, а вот последующие обрубаются так, что даже ping'и от них не проходят.

**Update4:** найден workaround. Я запустил на машине, на которой запущен **B**, команду *ping* до хостов, на которых запущены **C**. После этого отрубаться эти хосты перестали. Вместе с тем, понять, что же вызывает такую реакцию системы, пока не получается. *ufw* отключён.

**Update5:** проблема решена. Сервер не должен рвать соединение, надо дождаться, пока соединение разорвёт клиент (см. Update к комментарию).

Comment: А через какие устройства идет соеденения или может карту сети покажете?

Comment: До кучи, пробовали послушать/поанализировать трафик? `wireshark`\`ом, например.

Comment: без сорцов вряд ли что то можно сказать - в коде можно много чего наворотить. Но из самого простого - возможно, "сервер" биндиться тоько на ipv6, в этом случае при попытке подключиться локально на localhost все будет работать, а с другой машины - нет.

Comment: Akuma925, схема очень простая. Стоит маршрутизатор Allied Telesys 9028 (номер модели не точно помню), в него всё воткнуто. Всё в одной подсетке.

Comment: approximatenumber, спасибо, не догадался. Попробую послушать, как на объект попаду опять.

Comment: KoVadim, понял Вас, но этот вариант исключён. Адрес серверу указывается принудительно, в формате IPv4. Кроме того, сеть настроена через /etc/network/interfaces, и там данный интерфейс поднимается через iface eth0 inet static, так что IPv6, по идее, вообще подниматься не должен.

Comment: @BMP,  А на ваших машинах есть GUI? иногда бывает что networkmanager если его не отключить мешает настройкам через конфиги.

Comment: Akuma925, GUI есть, но network-manager я отключал. Кроме того, он же управляет только интерфейсами, не настроенными через  /etc/network/interfaces, поэтому вредить может максимум до первой перезагрузки. Однако версия у меня появилась - см. Update2 и Update3.

Comment: Думаю, проблема в основном не в ubunte, а в маршрутизаторе. Мне кажется, что именно он "режет" пакеты. А вот в чем разница (в каких флажках) в пакетах винды и убунты -- это и надо исследовать.

Comment: @avp, позавчера я вернулся ещё с одного объекта, где работает система. Там всё работает без проблем, хотя версии Ubuntu и нашего софта совпадают с проблемными случаями, и даже маршрутизатор такой же. Очередной подозреваемый - сетевуха. Будем поднимать ТТХ отправленных на объекты машин, искать закономерность, соответствие между типами (или хотя бы производителями) сетевух там, где всё работает, и где есть сбои.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Причины возникновения проблемы нашлись. Их было две. Одна - в тестовой системе, там серьёзные неполадки с сетью, и даже *ping*и теряются процентов на 30. Вторая и главная причина - в моём коде, сервер неправильно закрывал соединение. Обработав входящее соединение и сделав *socket->write()*, он висел на *socket->waitForBytesWritten()* (таким образом, до завершения отправки поток сервера был заблокирован), а после этого выполнял *socket->close()*. Видимо, такое принудительное закрытие сокета и не нравилось ОС. Когда я убрал *waitForBytesWritten()* и вместо *close()* сделал *disconnectFromHost()*, всё заработало.

**Update:** Заработало не всё. На сервере проблема осталась, workaround из Update4 помогает, пока конфигурация остаётся стационарной. Когда мы добавляем мобильный клиент, подключающийся из разных мест, с разных IP, добавить его в пингующий скрипт уже не получается, и он довольно скоро отваливается. На клиентах, даже стационарных, иногда появляются сообщения об обрыве и восстановлении связи. Решение проблемы нашёл только недавно.

Итак: когда сервер стал закрывать сокет более осторожно, через *disconnectFromHost*, проблема стала менее острой. Однако правильное решение оказалось таким: сервер вообще не должен закрывать сокет самостоятельно! Он должен реагировать на сигналы *disconnected* и *error*, по которым вызывает *deleteLater()*.

Когда сервер сам решает закрыть сокет, завершив отправку данных, возникает гонка сигналов. Сигнал об отключении с сервера может прилететь раньше, чем ответ сервера клиенту, и тогда мы на клиенте получаем ситуацию "сервер отключился - сервер подключился". А когда до сервера долетает запрос на отключение от клиента, а сокета уже нет, видимо, возникает аварийная ситуация, и накопление таких ситуаций приводит к блокировке IP клиента (под Linux. Windows такие запросы, похоже, просто игнорирует).

**Итог:** из сервера просто удалил disconnectFromHost(), и старый клиент работает (завершается неделя тестирования 2 клиента на 1 сервер) без единой потери связи. *Timeout*ы уменьшил с 400-600 мс до 10мс, и всё равно разрывов нет. Главный вывод: **сервер не должен закрывать соединение сам, он должен реагировать на сигналы** *disconnected* и *error*, возникающие вследствие действий клиента и среды передачи данных.